# Two wordpress installations in the same server using images from one wp-contet/uploads

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shared-hosting

I have two wordpress websites in one shared hosting, Installed in two separate folders in the public_html folder.

1) public_html/abc

2) public_html/xyz

Is there anyway i can use the images from public_html/abc/wp-content/uploads
as my images source for the website in public_html/xyz.

The reason i am trying to do this is, my hosting godaddy in restricting files allowed in the account to 250000. And most of the images in both my sites are common.

Comment: Use absolute path instead of using relative path.

Comment: @user2584538 I am referring to the already existing WordPress website. There are more than 5000 images in both of the installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the uploads folder in your wp-config.php file, more info here https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php under 'Moving uploads folder'

Comment: I did go through the codex. 
I tried
define('UPLOADS', '/path/to/my/uploads');

but the tricky part is, defining the uploads folder in wp-config, would be a security issue. as the path to my images in my xyz website will be shown as www.domain.com/abc/wp-content/uploads